# How can I achieve "jumps" with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-jump

I am developing a website that loads different pages depending on what menu icon a user clicks. A friend and I wrote this javascript function:

```
function loadPage(targetURL){
    $.get( targetURL, function( data ) {
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data;
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
}
```

And the menu icons are coded like this:

```
<img src="images/some_icon.png" title="Some Page" onclick="javascript:loadPage('pages/somePage.php')"/>
```

It works great except if trying to jump to a particular div id. For example,

```
<img src="images/some_icon.png" title="Some Page" onclick="javascript:loadPage('pages/somePage#someLocationOnPage.php')"/>
```

Taking out the .scrollTo(0,0) doesn't solve the issue. I put that line in to ensure that the page is scrolled all the way up when changing pages (Otherwise, if you were in the middle of the page and clicked a menu icon, the new page would display in the middle of the page).

What have I missed? How can I get the link to jump to a div id?

Comment: First verify that the function is called. Use console.log or alert() or such.

Comment: Verified. Function is indeed being called.

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop($('#'+targetUrl.split('#')[1].split('.php')[0]).position().top);` extremly rough.

Comment: Is this in place of the line

    window.scrollTo(0,0);

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two URL's are not different. The one with the bookmark just gets the same HTML code. Since you are not telling the browser to go to a specific bookmark, it should display the same information. (Unless your server sends different info for that link, of course)

I guess you'd have to manually move the view to the bookmark you want.

```
function loadPage(targetURL, targetID){
    $.get( targetURL, function( data ) {
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data;
        if(targetID && $("#"+targetID).length != 0){
            $(document).scrollTop($("#"+targetID).offset().top);
        } 
        else {
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
    });
}
```

And then give the ID for the target as another parameter. If that's not possible, you can also search for `#` in the url and find the ID/ or anchor.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but this solution actually breaks my website even more. I'm pretty new to javascript, so I'm unable to find your error. And yes, I remembered to change #someLocation to the real id. :-) If I could get something as quick as this to work, I would. But is it bad practice to not have a more general solution?

Comment: What you mean by it breaks? where does it go wrong? I fixed the closing brackets. I hope you saw that.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that fix. Yes, the other links work now, but the jumping one does not. I would use this function like   
  
    <img src="images/some_icon.png" title="Some Page" onclick="javascript:loadPage('pages/somePage, #someLocationOnPage.php')"/>  
  
right?

Comment: break the quotes to get two parameters. and the `.php` part should go with the url. `<img src="images/some_icon.png" title="Some Page" onclick="javascript:loadPage('pages/somePage.php', 'someLocationOnPage')"/>` EDIT: also remove the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should keep the `window.scrollTo(0,0)` in your code to keep the page go to top on every click of menu item.

Secondly if on click of menu icon which is calling

```
 loadPage('pages/somePage#someLocationOnPage.php')
```

your intentions are to open 'somePage' and scroll to the position where element id is 'someLocationOnPage.php' then you should update your loadPage method to check for the part after '#'.

```
function loadPage(targetURL){
    $.get( targetURL, function( data ) {
      document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data;
      window.scrollTo(0,0);

      // Grab url part after '#'
      var name = targetURL.substr( href.indexOf('#') + 1 ), target = $('a[name='+ name +']'), target2 = $('#' + name);

      // Determine of bookmark is available or not
      target = (target.length)? target : target2;

      // Scroll to the bookmark
       $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
       },400);
    });
}
```

Comment: With this solution, all the links work as expected... _except_ the one that jumps to the #. :(